# How can I construct and visualize a hypergraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

A hypergraph is a generalization of a graph, in which an edge can connect more than two vertices. Thus you can think of an edge in an hypergraph as a subset of nodes.

Since version 8, *Mathematica* has supported the plotting of graphs, as well as graph algorithms.

**Is there a way to plot hypergraphs on *Mathematica*?** I know there are ways in which an hypergraph can be represented as a graph, or a matrix. But what I want is a method that allows me to plot the hypergraph directly, where edges that connect multiple vertices are drawn as branching lines between those vertices (for example, think of a reaction network). See, for example, the first image in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108064/19017).

Answer (score 29):

Something similar to one in the Op's link:

```
hyperPlot[sets_, blayout_: "SpringEmbedding"] :=

 Block[{l, esym, eset, vset, g, em, rules, edges, vcircle},
  l = Length[sets];
  esym = Table[Unique["e"], {l}];
  eset = Flatten[Table[Thread[sets[[i]] <-> esym[[i]]], {i, l}]];
  vset = Union[Join @@ sets];
  g = Graph[vset, eset, GraphLayout -> blayout];
  em = GraphEmbedding[g];
  rules = Dispatch[Thread[VertexList[g] -> em]];
  edges = 
   Table[{ColorData["DarkRainbow"][i/l], 
     Arrow[BSplineCurve[{sets[[i, 1]], esym[[i]], #} /. rules, 
         SplineWeights -> {1, 6, 1}], {.2, .2}] & /@ 
      Rest[sets[[i]]]}, {i, l}];
  vcircle = 
   With[{c = # /. rules}, {Text[Style[#, Bold, 13], c], 
       Circle[c, .2]}] & /@ vset;
  Graphics[{{Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0], edges}, Thickness[.005], 
    vcircle}]
  ]
```

basically, I added dummy vertex to each sets to define edges and construct graph.
Using embedding information, I will draw graph and edges. It's not perfect, but another possibility. Also you could draw directed hyper graph..

```
vs = {{2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 9, 12, 6, 7}, {8, 2, 11, 13}, {1, 8, 10}};
hyperPlot[vs]
```

[image]

```
vs = RandomSample[Subsets[Range[10], {3}], 10];
hyperPlot[vs, "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]
```

[image]

```
vs = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {3, 4, 7}, {5, 6, 7}};
hyperPlot[vs]
```

[image]

Comment: This would make a nice function repository item. The current [HypergraphPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HypergraphPlot) (which is very similar to Vitaliy's) is not really usable in practice (too often a region includes vertices that it should not). Your version is much more practical.

Comment: @Szabolcs it's in function repository now.

Comment: @halmir I'd like to use this but in my application, but I need to specify vertex positions. By editing this and passing in a value for the `em` variable it seems I need to provide the edge position data in addition. Is there a way to modify so we only specify vertex positions? Also, can you please give a link to the function repo where this is located?

Comment: @nasosev I submitted new version to support VertexCoordinates and here's the l ink: 
 https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HypergraphPlot/?i=HypergraphPlot&searchapi=https%3A%2F%2Fresources.wolframcloud.com%2FFunctionRepository%2Fsearch

Comment: @halmir Wow, thank you!! It seems like the version at that link hasn't updated yet: it says latest version '2.0.0 – 09 March 2020' and in the source I didn't see a way to provide VertexCoordinates. Is the update not online yet? Thanks again!

Comment: @nasosev updated is not online yet.. it's reviewing now

Answer (score 20):

Here is a different take on @Szabolcs idea. If a general grouping will do CommunityGraphPlot can be used. Define a 13-vertex graph with no simple (as opposed to hyper) edges:

```
g = Graph[Range[13], {}, 
     VertexCoordinates -> RandomReal[1, {13, 2}], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Explicetely define hyper-edges as groups of vertices they connect:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g,
 {{2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 9, 12, 6, 7}, {8, 2, 11, 13}, {1, 8, 10}},
 CommunityRegionStyle -> RandomColor[RGBColor[_, _, _, .5], 4]]
```

[image]

Use Method option for different layouts:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g,
 {{2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 9, 12, 6, 7}, {8, 2, 11, 13}, {1, 8, 10}},
 CommunityRegionStyle -> RandomColor[RGBColor[_, _, _, .5], 4], Method -> "Hierarchical"]
```

[image]

Comment: This is much better than mine.  I only did it for 3-hypergraphs, this is probably more general.  Is there a guarantee that a region will never contain a node that should not be part of it?  This is actually a non-trivial layout problem that I didn't know how to solve for the general case.  If `CommunityGraphPlot` guarantees this, then I want to delete my answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs I do not think there is a guarantee. I can ask for certainty, but just by poking around I've seen this violated.

Comment: @Szabolcs ...but coloring of vertices helps a bit.

Comment: If the $n$ vertices are arranged on a regular $n$-gon (or they're just put on a circle), then it is automatically guaranteed that a polygon made of a subset of the vertices won't contain anything but that subset.  This at least shows that this is *possible*.  Putting the vertices on a circle may not be a very efficient arrangement though.  I think CommunityGraphPlot doesn't support CircularEmbedding, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs I did not find an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

This is just a rough proof-of-concept that needs additional work for real applications.

For 3-hypergraphs, you could simply surround each triple with a rounded polygon.  I didn't implement rounded polygons now (which would look better), I just used B-splines, but these are a but ugly.

```
hg = RandomSample[Subsets[Range[10], {3}], 10]
(* {{2, 5, 6}, {3, 5, 9}, {2, 4, 10}, {2, 6, 9}, {1, 4, 7}, {4, 
  6, 9}, {1, 6, 10}, {4, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 7}, {3, 8, 10}} *)

cg[n_] := Graph[n, UndirectedEdge @@@ Subsets[n, {2}]]

g = GraphUnion @@ (cg /@ hg);

pos = GraphEmbedding[g];

dt = Dispatch@Thread[VertexList[g] -> pos];

expand[pts_] := 
 With[{c = Mean[pts]}, # + c & /@ (1.8 (# - c & /@ pts))]

Graphics[{Disk[#, 0.03] & /@ pos, 
  FaceForm@Directive[Darker@Blue, Opacity[0.1]], EdgeForm[Black], 
  FilledCurve@BSplineCurve[#, SplineClosed -> True] & /@ 
   expand /@ (hg /. dt)}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't know anything about hypregs. Just a question: Are they always undirected?

Comment: Nice visual @belisarius! What about n-edges? Found this on the demonstrations site:  http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ThreeUniformHypergraphs/

Comment: @belisarius, oriented hyerpgraphs have been studied recently, see the work by Reff and Rusnak, esp the latter's thesis in 2010.

Answer (score 4):

For generating large ones (without many hyperedge overlaps) [WolframModelPlot](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/WolframModelPlot) works well:

```
ResourceFunction[
 "WolframModelPlot"][{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7, 1}}]
```

[image]
[image]

There is also a [Hypergraph paclet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframInstitute/Hypergraph/) in development with some flexibale styles, which tries to make hypergraphs behave like native objects, similar to Graphs:

```
Table[PacletSymbol["WolframInstitute/Hypergraph", "RandomHypergraph"][
  10, {{3, 1}, {5, 2}, {4, 3}}], 3]
```

[image]

It also has a [dynamic widget](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/resources/WolframInstitute/Hypergraph/ref/HypergraphDraw.html) for manipulating hypergraphs:

[image]

And 3D hypergraphs:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ResourceFunction["RandomHypergraph"][{10, {8, 2}}]

ResourceFunction["SimpleHypergraphPlot"][%]
```

[image]